# Vaadin Design View for a Composite Component is not visible after closing and opening it again

Tags: eclipse, vaadin7, designview

The design view for a composite component in Eclipse is not visible after closing the tab once and opening it again. This is bizzare.

Comment: can you add your code here?

Comment: It's a generic problem in my installation. It happens to all composite components after a few opening and closing of tabs.